# how to use/store JSON data after the callback has fired?

Tags: javascript

**alert:**

Basic javascript question... How can I get the data from the success handling and return a JSON object?

Is there a away that I can place this code:

```
function Geo() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
            I DONT WANT TO USE position here... 
            I want to place it in a var like so...
            this.data = position; // or something similar?

        },
        function errorCallback(error) {
            //do error handling
        }
    );
}
var geo = new Geo();
geo.????? how can I get that data?
```

I tried this but it `this.data` comes back undefined

Inside a function and call that function to get the data? I want to get that data on damand and use that data to populate different fields. I can't always use that data right there and then.

```
var data = ???
```

Comment: You have to do it in the callback; that's the whole point.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: so I am going to have to copy this code EVERYTIME I need data? WTF?

Comment: See [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that getCurrentPosition() is an AJAX call, so you'll need to define a callback, so your JS execution doesn't just hang while its waiting for it.

```
function Geo(cb) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {
        I DONT WANT TO USE position here... 
        I want to place it in a var like so...
        cb(null, position);
        this.data = position; // or something similar?

    },
    function errorCallback(error) {
        //do error handling
        cb(error);
    }
  );
}



var geo = new Geo(function(err, data){
   //this will be executed once the data is actually ready
   if(err) {
      console.log(err); //handle the error
   } else {
     console.log(data); //handle success
   }
});
```

Comment: I am so sad that this is the only solution that javascript provides. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Phil Sad? What were you hoping for? JS is event based, so this currently is the cleanest way to handle it's event-based nature. This is usually pretty clean. If you are seeing pain from this solution, there may be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not doing it wrong, I just had a wrong idea of when I wanted the data. This solution, in retrospect, is really nice.