# Google Maps Places API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm a Javascript newbie and I can't seem to get this script working.

Managed to get the geolocation working but no places markers show when loaded.
Tried a lot of stuff can you guys help me out?

```
    var map;

    function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 13
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    var input = document.getElementById('searchtxt');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
    } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
    var request = {
        location: pos,
        radius: 1500,
        types: ['restaurant']
    };
    alert('OK -> ' + request); //THIS DOESN'T SHOW. WHY??
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}
function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  map.setCenter(options.position);
}


function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    } else {
}
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Even the ALERT doesn't show, but if I put it before the var request statement it does show: "OK -> Undefined".

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: did you even check back after reading the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCurrentPosition()` gets fired asynchronously. This means that the `var pos` variable isn't set in this scope. This leaves `pos` undefined. This  throws an error when you attempt to set it in the `var options` object. This breaks the code and the `alert()` is never fired.

The `alert()` works before the object because the erroneous assignment, `location: pos,` hasn't happened yet.

This error was clearly displayed in the console so I would suggest learning to debug that way.

Here is a question that I asked a'while back that might help you:
[how to use/store JSON data after the callback has fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788825/how-to-use-store-json-data-after-the-callback-has-fired)

Comment: Thanks Phil.
I Understand the problem and will try to correct it.
I'm a real javascript newbie and having a hard time trying to learn it. I'll define the pos in a var so i can use it afterwards on the code.
Thanks again.